# why my Firebase deployed web application doesn't work properly?

Tags: angular, firebase

I am working on a web application which has http post function. The application is build base on angular 6 and deployed on firebase for test.

In the application, a specific data is send to server every 3s by http post function. Data is successfully send to the server when the application is run locally: http://localhost:4200. (Server log show the data is correctly received); however, after I deployed the app in the firebase and open the application's firebase url, the application's http function doesn't work.

Could you please help?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: I find this issue is caused by mixed http url and https url.